# How to edit a cell's value depending on complex condition in EXCEL (google spreadsheet)

Tags: excel, documentation

I would like to aplly a condition on a cell. My goal would be this:

Depending on a string used in for example column A (A:A), I would like to automatically update a cell of my choice, so that it reduces the value by the corresponding B column (besides the dependency string in A).

In other words, for example (rusty english, excuse me):

I have a value of 100000 in a cell of choice. I have a B column full of expenses (integers). 'A' column contains either a string of "x" or "a". I would like to reduce the value of my cell of choice by a value in the B column, where A column's cell has an 'x' as a string. Sort of a "responsibility" table, where I pay and amount, and I stand for X, my value will be reduced by the B column's amount, where 'A' has a string of "x".

I hope it is clear, sorry for wall of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like, in D1 and drag down:

```
=if(A1="x",C1-B1,C1)
```

[image]